# How to vertically align side bar alongside a main content div on one row

Tags: html, css

I'm following this CSS guide: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GNGtLbRyI4&list=PLr6-GrHUlVf8JIgLcu3sHigvQjTw_aC9C&index=66
and when I replicate the CSS code, I get this problem: the two elements don't align vertically on the row, like shown in the image.

Here's the screenshot of the problem: 
[image]

I tried changing margin, padding of the two div element but I can't get it to work. When I use inspect element, the margins are just fine, I just see that in that space between the main content and the navigation bar I can select what seems to be a blank character. I would like to follow the tutorial exactly as it is and keep things simple, and I don't understand why it doesn't work on my end.

HTML:

```
<body>
     <div id="header"></div>
     <div id="navbar"></div>
     <div class="sideright">
         <p>Links here</p>
     </div>
     <div class="maincontent">
        <p>Content here</p>
     </div>
 </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #757CA4;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#header {
    background-color: #323A6F;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 80px;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #323A6F;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
   height: 35px;
}

.maincontent {
    background-color: #D1D3E2;
    margin: 10px 320px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 110%;
}

.sideright {
    background-color: #D1D3E2;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 105%;
    float: right;
    width: 260px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seemed to have had an odd space after the closing tag of `<div class="sideright">` that showed up when I copied the HTML into the environment.  It showed up as a `/ufeff` in codepen.  When I removed it, it worked.

Check my codepen and you'll see the layout you want.

https://codepen.io/tylerp33/pen/QYNLWN

```
<body>
     <div id="header"></div>
     <div id="navbar"></div>
     <div class="sideright">
         <p>Links here</p>
     </div>
     <div class="maincontent">
        <p>Content here</p>
     </div>
 </body>
```

Copy paste what is above and you should be fine.

EDIT:  Correction; the character that I removed in codepen is Unicode Character `&#65279`, which is 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' or U+FEFF.  You may have copied the code without knowing it using copy/paste.  Also, now you know your current text editor is not displaying unicode characters (oddly enough, mine isn't either).

Here is a helpful solution that I stumbled upon:

> One option is to open the file in a very basic text editor that
>   doesn't understand unicode, or one that understands it but has the
>   ability to display any non-ascii characters using their actual codes.
>
> Once you locate it, you can delete the small block of text around it
>   and retype that text manually.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're right, that was the problem. Thanks a lot! Next time a situation like this pops up, how can I see such characters?

Comment: Not a problem!  What an odd little bug (my editor didn't show it either).  Check my edited answer for a little more insight.